# how to implement locking within function in multiple threads f#

Tags: multithreading, f#, locking, threadpool

I created a mutable list called tickets that contains type Ticket.
I also have a bookSeat function that imitates booking a seat.Since F# list type is immutable, my bookSeat function always returns a new, modified, copy of tickets list.

```
open System
open System.Threading

type Ticket = {seat:int; customer:string}
let mutable tickets = [for n in 1..10 -> {Ticket.seat = n; Ticket.customer = ""}]
let bookSeat _ =
    Console.WriteLine("Enter seat number: ")
    let seatNo = int(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Enter customer name: ")
    let name = string(Console.ReadLine())
    let book seatNo name tickets = 
        tickets |> List.map (fun ticket ->
            if ticket.seat = seatNo then { ticket with customer = name }
            else ticket )    
    tickets <- book seatNo name tickets
```

I now want to create two threads that both invoke bookSeat and i want to implement locking within bookSeat to avoid a race condition.

I came up with this new bookSeat function (still very new to programming and f#, code might seem very rookie issh)

```
let seatNo = ref 0
let name = ref ""

let bookSeat _ =
    Console.WriteLine("Enter seat number: ")
    seatNo :=  int(Console.ReadLine())
    Console.WriteLine("Enter customer name: ")
    name:= string(Console.ReadLine().ToString())
    let book seatNo name tickets = 
        lock(seatNo,name) (fun()-> tickets |> List.map (fun ticket ->
            if ticket.seat = seatNo then { ticket with customer = name }
            else ticket ))    
    tickets <- book !seatNo !name tickets

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(bookSeat)) |> ignore
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(bookSeat)) |> ignore
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

The code compiles successfully but has an error when i run it. It outputs this followed by an error below

```
Enter seat number: 
Enter seat number: 5
Enter customer name: charles

Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer & number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal).....
```

The error message is quite lengthy, would've posted a picture, but i don't have enough reputation to do so yet..

How can i successfully implement locking within my bookSeat function and invoke it within multiple threads at run time?

Comment: This error has nothing to do with locking. Is produced when you're trying to convert a string to number.

Comment: If you look further down the stack trace you'll find where in your code you are making the call that eventually throws.

Comment: is it only me or is this kind of "wrong architecture"? thought parts of the idea of using functional programming is to avoid issues like this... 

would it not be better to just drop lock and use some variant of agent/mailbox? then a "first come first serve" applies and since only one is accessing the list at all times, no lock necessary.

Comment: @user<lots of digits>: It's not only you. I agree that mailbox processing is a better alternative or maybe transactional memory. See http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/software-transactional-memory-and-f. Transactional memory is now a part of FSharpX: https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Extras/StmSample.html

Answer (score 0):

Your two threads are competing for the console; likely the input "charles" was consumed by a thread executing the `seatNo := int(Console.ReadLine()` assignment.

I agree with the comments on using Agents/MailboxProcessors, but if you want to do it with locks, lock the prompt-input sequences:

```
let bookSeat _ =
  lock (seatNo) (fun _ ->
    Console.WriteLine("Enter seat number: ")
    seatNo := int(Console.ReadLine())
  )
  lock (name) (fun _ -> 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter customer name: ")
    name:= string(Console.ReadLine().ToString()
  )
  ...
```